How to create ConfigMap yaml manifest for Azure Kubernetes using shell or PowerShell script?
I have requirement to create yaml file which can be used to create configmap in kubernetes.
I have 3 xml files which are need to be imported in template yaml file.
YAML Template:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config1.xml: |-
    <Sheet>
    .
    .
    .
    </Sheet>
  config2.xml: |-
    <Sheet>
    .
    .
    .
    
    </Sheet>
  config3.xml: |-
    <Sheet>
    .
    .
    </Sheet>
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{CMPlaceholder}}
  namespace: {{NSPlaceholder}}

xml file:
<Sheet>
    <Category name="Category1">
        <Item name="item1">Cat1Item1.value</Item>
        <Item name="item2">Cat1Item2.value</Item>
    </Category>
    <Category name="Category2">
        <Item name="item1">Cat2Item1.value</Item>
        <Item name="item2">Cat2Item2.value</Item>
    </Category>
    <Category name="Category3">
        <Item name="item1">Cat3Item1.value</Item>
        <Item name="item2">Cat3Item2.value</Item>
    </Category>
    <Category name="Groups">
        <Item name="Group1" commarea="Y">G1.Value</Item>
        <Item name="Group2" commarea="Y">G2.Value</Item>
        <Item name="Group3" commarea="Y">G3.Value</Item>
        <Group1 name="G1.Value">
            <spec name="ISOS">
                <specdetails name="name1">spvalue1</specdetails>
                <specdetails name="name2">spvalue2</specdetails>
                <specdetails name="name3">spvalue3</specdetails>
                <specdetails name="name4">spvalue4</specdetails>
            </spec>
        </Group1>

        .

        .
        <Group2 name="G2.Value"></Group2>

        .

        .
        <Group3 name="G3.Value"></Group3>

        .

        <Category name="FinalProducts">
            <Item name="Product1">Product1FinalValue</Item>
            <Item name="Product2">Product2FinalValue</Item>
            <Item name="Product3">Product3FinalValue</Item>
            <Item name="Product4">Product4FinalValue</Item>
        </Category>
    </Category>
</Sheet>

Similary I have 2 more xml files. I need some script to prepare the final YAML so that I can use it to create configmap in azure kubernetes service using below command
kubectl apply -f "YAMLFILEPATH"

Expecting script to take below arguments.
.\script.sh or .\script.ps1 -YamlTemplate "PathOfYAMLFile" -config1.xml "PathOfConfig1.xml" -config2.xml "PathOfConfig2.xml" -config3.xml "PathOfConfig3.xml" -configMapName "group-product-spec" -namespace "organization" 

Output of the script should be yaml created in the same directory with the name group-product-spec.yaml

Helm would probably be a more suitable tool for what you're trying to do.

We would expect to see code that you have tried. This is not a code writing service nor is this necessarily the correct place for suggestions...

Suppose you have three xml files, and you need to create script which can be used to create configmap in kubernetes.
I am showing via bash so let's say I create a create-configmap.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Function to display help message
function display_help() {
    echo "Usage: $0 -YamlTemplate <PathOfYAMLFile> -config1 <PathOfConfig1.xml> -config2 <PathOfConfig2.xml> -config3 <PathOfConfig3.xml> -configMapName <group-product-spec> -namespace <organization>"
    exit 1
}


while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -YamlTemplate)
            YamlTemplate="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -config1)
            Config1="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -config2)
            Config2="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -config3)
            Config3="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -configMapName)
            ConfigMapName="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -namespace)
            Namespace="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        *)
            display_help
            ;;
    esac
done

# Check if all required arguments are provided
if [ -z "$YamlTemplate" ] || [ -z "$Config1" ] || [ -z "$Config2" ] || [ -z "$Config3" ] || [ -z "$ConfigMapName" ] || [ -z "$Namespace" ]; then
    display_help
fi

# Read the content of XML files
Config1Content=$(cat "$Config1")
Config2Content=$(cat "$Config2")
Config3Content=$(cat "$Config3")

# Create the final YAML file by replacing placeholders
OutputYaml="${ConfigMapName}.yaml"
cat <<EOF > "$OutputYaml"
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config1.xml: |-
$(echo "$Config1Content" | sed 's/^/    /')
  config2.xml: |-
$(echo "$Config2Content" | sed 's/^/    /')
  config3.xml: |-
$(echo "$Config3Content" | sed 's/^/    /')
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: $ConfigMapName
  namespace: $Namespace
EOF

echo "ConfigMap YAML file created at $OutputYaml"

Make the script executable chmod +x create-configmap.sh
Run the script
./create-configmap.sh -YamlTemplate "template.yaml" -config1 "config1.xml" -config2 "config2.xml" -config3 "config3.xml" -configMapName "group-product-spec" -namespace "<whatever_is_your_namespace>"

and finally check using kubectl get configmap group-product-spec

and if you describe it, you can see your xml loaded properly
kubectl describe configmap group-product-spec -n default


